# Why is the nodejs command not executed with crontab

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cron

I try to run a node command through the crontab, but without success. The code i use in crontab is

`*\1 * * * * /usr/bin/node /root/darwin/test.js`

when i run the `/usr/bin/node /root/darwin/test.js` in my ubuntu (18.04) server the test.js code works fine. The problem is with the crontab.

I have tried to re-installed the cron service. I checked that the cron service is up and working. I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `*\1` needs to be `*/1`. If that is so then the reason it isn't being ran is that the line is being ignored by cron because it is invalid. You might want to look at the system logs for cron to see if it outputted a parse error.

Comment: i've changed it as you suggested but it didn't work. I have also tried ```* * * * * /usr/bin/node /root/darwin/test.js``` but it didn't work too

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the mysql server and then the above error was fixed. The next error i found was

(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

to solve this error i modifiled my cron as

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/node /root/darwin/test.js >> /var/log/testfile.log
```

the most important was to export a log file. 
Now everything works